# The type namespace name IdentityUser could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I keep getting this error for the last two frameworks that I have included. I have searched up and down. Can't figure what it is. I have installed the NuGet packages and tried to recompile multiple times. Nothing is working. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using IdentityUser;
using IdentityDbContext;

namespace UserProfileInfo.Models
{
    public class UserProfile : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual UserProfile UserInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserProfileDB
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserProfile>
    {
        public MyDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UserProfile> UserInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @stack-flow can you add - `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;` and let me know what happens? Also in the references you see if that DLL us added or not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no needs for -

```
using IdentityUser;
using IdentityDbContext;
```

Instead you need to add following -

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Make sure you have that DLL as a reference as shown below. If it is not available, then you can get that nuget from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is for Dotnet Core and you will not receive any warning

> `using  Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores`

Answer (score 2):

For AspNet Core 1 use NuGet:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore

For AspNet Core 2 use NuGet:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

Comment: Actually, it's `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;` Kudos https://stackoverflow.com/a/45830945/1011591