# Can't inherit from IdentityUser and IdentityRole in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to finish updating to .NET Core 2.0 but a couple of errors pop up:

**The problem:**

I have two classes, ApplicationRole and ApplicationUser which inherit some properties from IdentityRole and IdentityUser.

With the update to Core 2.0 I'm getting the following errors, claiming that IdentityRole and IdentityUser could not be found.

However, the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0` is installed in the new version of .NET Core

**About IdentityRole:**

*Message 1:*

> The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (is it missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

*Message 2:*

> The 'Application.Models.ApplicationRole' type can not be used as a parameter of type 'TRole' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext '. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Application.Models.ApplicationRole' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole '.

*Definition of ApplicationRole:*

```
public class ApplicationRole:IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDated { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**About IdentityUser:**

*Message 1:*

> The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (is it missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

*Message 2:*

> The 'Application.Models.ApplicationUser' type can not be used as a parameter of type 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext '. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Application.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser '.

*Definition of ApplicationUser*

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The guide followed to define this classes and their use are here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-mvc-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core/

With the change to Core 2.0 I wonder how IdentityRole and IdentityUser changed so I can no longer inherit from them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved.

The package that was keeping those classes `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` changed. To access those clases (`IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`) one must add

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
```

With this, the problem is gone.

Comment: did you figure out how to use Roles on .Net Core 2.0? If so could you please give an example

Comment: @YTerle review new answer.

Answer (score 8):

`ICollection<IdentityUserRole<int>> Roles` , `ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<int>> Claims` and `ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<int>> Logins` navigation properties have been removed from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser` .

You should define them manually

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{                
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<int>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<int>>();

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<int>> Claims { get; } = new List<IdentityUserClaim<int>>();

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<int>> Logins { get; } = new List<IdentityUserLogin<int>>();
}
```

To prevent duplicate foreign keys when running EF Core Migrations, add the following to your `IdentityDbContext` class' `OnModelCreating` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(builder);

builder.Entity<MyUser>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.Entity<MyUser>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Logins)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.Entity<MyUser>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

[Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)

Answer (score 7):

For me it got solved by installing package:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores
```

Comment: if someone comes from the future on 3.1 version, definitely this is the one than you need to install.

Answer (score 2):

This happen to me but I was using Asp.net Core with traditional .NET Framework. You need to add the Nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity`. That contains the classes `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`.

I think the reason you have to add this is when your project isn't using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework
```

or

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework
```